# How to get the text written in text input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to grab the txt I wrote inside the my `<input type="text">` but it is returning `undefined` , I tried many ways such as `.text()` or `.html()` or `e.target.value` , all of them returned `undefined` including this `innerHTML` too

```
   $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
        alert($('input[type=text]').innerHTML);

      }
   });
```

Comment: What about `alert( $(this).val() )`?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it is working thanks , but why ? what is the difference ?

Comment: An `input` has a value, not some `txt` or `html`... By the way, `e.target.value` should have worked.

Comment: oh, I think I have syntax error or something , .val() actually worked but e.target.value didn't ... I will check out , thanks. and how you can mark the text as code in comment section?

Comment: how you can mark the text as code: Using some back ticks ` ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette good , thanks 

Comment: All about formating is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery with Vanilla and they aren't the same. First of all, this was not going to work either way because form elements have **values**, not **HTML**. However, lets say you had tried this: `alert($('input[type=text]').value);`

`value` is a property of an html input element, but does not exist in a jQuery object. The jQuery object represents the form element, but wraps it in an extra set of properties and methods. If you truly wanted to mix them you could reference the form element from the jQuery object like:

```
alert($('input[type=text]')[0].value);
```

But it's better for legibility and consistency to stay with one or the other, which in jQuery would be

```
alert($('input[type=text]').val());
```

but as you're inside a jQuery event handler for that element, you can get it with

```
alert($(this).val());
```